# Turn Stellar.js on and off runtime

Tags: javascript, stellar.js

Is there a way to turn stellar.js on and off in code? I've tried to call "stellar" method with different parameters but seems like it only works once:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.stellar({
                verticalScrolling: true,
                verticalOffset: 0,
            });

        $.stellar({
                verticalScrolling: false, // is not turning scrolling off
                verticalOffset: 0,
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reload the plugin, reset it before calling initialization function.

Check the function code in stellar.js. If the options === 'destroy', plugin stellar is reset.

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    var args = arguments;
    if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {
        return this.each(function () {
            var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
            if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {
                instance[options].apply(instance, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            }
            if (options === 'destroy') {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, null);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

So your code could be as following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.stellar({
            verticalScrolling: true,
            verticalOffset: 0,
        });

    $.stellar("destroy");

    $.stellar({
            verticalScrolling: false, // is not turning scrolling off
            verticalOffset: 0,
        });

});
```